# The integration of Poisson kernel and write it in real form

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm a beginner of complex analysis.  I have some questions about the Poisson kernel.

Suppose $D(0,1)$ is a unite disk on $\mathbb{C}$ and $z \in D$ , $\zeta \in \partial D$ . Define $\zeta=e^{i \phi}$ .

From my textbook"Concise Complex Analysis", I learned the definition of Poisson kernel has the following equivalent expressions:  $$\begin{align*}
P(\zeta,z) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-\overline{z}e^{i \phi}|^2} =\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1-\left| z \right| ^2}{|\zeta-z|^2}= \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{|\zeta|^2-|z|^2}{|\zeta-z|^2}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left( \frac{\zeta}{\zeta-z}+\frac{\overline{z}}{\overline{\zeta}-\overline{z}} \right)
\end{align*}$$ Also, the Poisson kernel is considered as $$\begin{align*}
P(\zeta,z)= \mathrm{Re}\left( \frac{\zeta+z}{\zeta-z} \right) =\frac{1-|z|^2}{|\zeta-z|^2}
\end{align*}$$ Then my first question is: how should I turn the Poisson kernel into a real expression. I searched on Wiki and other answers. They start by stating that the definition of Poisson kernel is $$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Re}\left( \frac{1+r^{i \theta}}{1- r^{ i \theta}} \right) 
\end{align*}$$ I don't quite know how to write the Poisson kernel in real expression by the definition from my book. (Also, I don't know Fourier analysis, if it's possible, please avoid using it.)

---

My second question is about proving the following integral: $$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} P(\zeta,z) \ d\zeta=1
\end{align*}$$
I tried to use the equivalent form of Poisson kernel to rewrite the integral as the following: $$\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2 \pi} P(\zeta,z) \ d\zeta= \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{1-|z|^2}{|\zeta-z|^2} e^{i \phi} \cdot i \ d\phi
\end{align*}$$ However, I don't know how should I continue this. I indeed found answers to proving this integral, but all the answers I found use the real expression of the Poisson kernel.

As a result, if the integral can be evaluated by complex integration, I don't know how to do it. If in order to evaluate the integral, one must write out the real expression of the Poisson kernel, I don't know how to write the real expression of it by using my definition.

Any help on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because $z$ lies inside the unit disc, let $0\le r<1$ and $0\le\theta<2\pi$ be chosen such that $z=re^{i\theta}$, so by the law of cosines we have

$$
|\zeta-z|^2=|\zeta|^2+|z|^2-2|\zeta|\cdot|z|\cos(\theta-\phi)=1-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2
$$

Therefore, we obtain

$$
P(\zeta,z)={1-|z|^2\over|\zeta-z|^2}={1-r^2\over1-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2}.
$$
You can even go further using the expression $P(\zeta,z)=\Re[(\zeta+z)/(\zeta-z)]$:
$$
P(\zeta,z)=1+\Re\left(2re^{i(\theta-\phi)}\over1-re^{i(\theta-\phi)}\right)=1+2\sum_{n\ge1}r^n\cos[n(\theta-\phi)].
$$